# Mexican visa with Philippine passport + UK Residence card + married to Spanish citizen

Tags: visas, mexico, uk-citizens, filipino-citizens

I would like to know if anybody can advise me how to proceed with this matter. My wife is from the Philippines, and in the future we would like to visit Mexico.

As far as I know I don't need visa as long as we stay less than 21 days. My wife has the EEA2/Family permit. But I don't know if this has any kind of validity/use outside Europe or she need to get a visa to visit Mexico. We both live in UK but I'm from Spain.

Comment: Before I answer this question, can I confirm that the EEA2 permit has the words 'indefinite leave to remain' written on it?

Comment: No, the EEA2 said "Married to a EEA Citizen" she can ask for the leave to remain permit in 4 years (I think).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the visa rules for Mexico that I got off IATA, the rules say (for Philippines passport holders):

> Visa required, except for a stay of max. 180 days:
>
> - for alien residents of United Kingdom holding a **permanent residence permit**.
> - for holders of a valid visa for the USA.

CIBT elaborates that no visa is required for people who:

> Hold permanent residency for one of the Schengen member states,
>   Canada, Japan, UK or a valid visa for USA

UKBA defines permanent residency as 'indefinite leave to remain'. From the fact that you mention in your comment that your wife has the right to remain for four years, [it appears she is on her 'qualifying / probationary period'](http://www.ukba.homeoffice.gov.uk/visas-immigration/partners-families/citizens-settled/spouse-cp/how-long/).

It would thus appear that your wife does not yet have a permanent resident permit in the UK and needs to apply for Mexican tourist visa to go there.

Comment: Thanks. I think you are right.. now reading about the EEA2 I saw  "`After you have lived in the United Kingdom for a continuous period of five years you can apply for confirmation of your permanent residence.`". And her visa is valid for 5 years.. so Everything is more clear now..